# Very basic AChartEngine XY

Tags: achartengine

I've been trying for hours to get something as simple as displaying a line chart based on 2 dots that I supply manually and all I get is a crash. I've tried to understand how everything works based on the demo code but it's too complex. I'm not even concerned about writing nice code with onResume() etc, I just want something to display the first time I open the activity. Once I know how to do that I'll be able to adapt and learn what I need. Here's the code I came up with:

```
 public class StatsActivity extends Activity {
 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset StatsDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
 private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer StatsRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
 private XYSeries StatsCurrentSeries;
 private GraphicalView StatsChartView;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     setContentView(R.layout.stats);
     LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Statschart);
     StatsRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.YELLOW);
     String seriesTitle = "Rank";
     XYSeries series = new XYSeries(seriesTitle);
         series.add(5, 7); //1st series I want to add
     StatsDataset.addSeries(series);
         series.add(9, 1); //the 2nd one
     StatsDataset.addSeries(series);
     StatsCurrentSeries = series;
     System.out.println(series);
     XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
     renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
     StatsRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
     StatsChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, StatsDataset,StatsRenderer); 
     layout.addView(StatsChartView);    
 }
}
```

I've been reading the docs to determine what each function does but in the end I still can't get anything to display.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The big thing that I struggled with is that you need a renderer for each XYSeries. You have two series here, but just one renderer - I just create/add renderers when I input data. Also, Android is mostly pass-by-reference, so you've passed the same data set in twice (i.e. your second update to the data will be mirrored "in" the MultipleSeriesDataset).